# Web Essential 2013 for Update 4 (V2.5.1)

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I just updated my Visual Studio 2013 to Update 4.  I opened one of my existing projects without any problem.  However, after I updated the Web Essential 2013 for Update 4 using the Extension and Update Manager, I no longer can open my project.  It always causes Visual Studio 2013 to stop working and the Just-In-Time Debugger indicates an unhandled exception occurred in devenv.exe[6336].  When I disabled or uninstalled the Web Essential, the problem went away.  Does anyone know how to fix the problem? I deleted the .suo.  I also tried creating a project from scratch, it still crashes. Thanks.

Comment: I am experiencing a similar problem, did you ever sort this out?

Comment: yes, the latest version seems to fixed the problem.  Just remove the old version and get new version from nuget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version seems to fixed the problem. Just remove the old version and get new version from nuget. –  user266909 1 hour ago

Comment: Thanks for following up on this! I was only the nightly build v.2.5.3.1, and didn't notice that they released v2.5.4.  I updated and so far, so good!